# Gapi is not defined in react app to acces google sheets api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-api-js-client

I am trying to send data from an HTML Form in a React.js web app to a google sheet.

I have added the script tag in index.html (tried in `<head>` and in `<body>`) but gapi is still undified.

```html
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
  </script>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

in the component I do this:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this); 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleClientLoad();
  }

  handleClientLoad = () => {
    gapi.load("client:auth2", this.initClient);
  };
  updateSignInStatus() {}
  initClient = () => {
    gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPE,
        discoveryDocs: [
          "https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4",
        ],
      })
      .then(() => {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSignInStatus);
        this.updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      });
  };

  onFormSubmit(submissionValues) {
    const params = {
      spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: "Sheet1",
      valueInputOption: "RAW",
      insertDataOption: "INSERT_ROWS", 
    };

    const valueRangeBody = {
      majorDimension: "ROWS", 
      values: [submissionValues], 
    };

    let request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(
      params,
      valueRangeBody
    );
    request.then(
      function (response) {
        console.log(response.result);
      },
      function (reason) {
        console.error("error: " + reason.result.error.message);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="Form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
   ...)};
}
```

I also tried doing `window.gapi` with no result.
I know it's gapi not being loaded before the component but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the script tag to load gapi you can use [gapi-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-script) package as this package provides the gapi instantly, so you don't have to wait for any script to load, just import it and use